# Is there a source that explains or defines terms like Theorem, Proposition, Lemma and Corollary?

Tags: terminology, online-resources

> I will write the German names of the following English terms in
>   brackets as it is important that I use the correct terms. This is a
>   question about terms and I'm not completely sure if I've translated everything correctly.

I'm currently writing digital lecture notes (in German). The makes use of the following "theorem-like" mathematical statements:

- Remark ("Bemerkung" in German)
- Proposition ("Proposition" in German)
- Theorem ("Satz" in German)

He proved all of those statements. As it feels strange to me to prove remarks, I called them corollary ("Korollar" in German). Today, he told me that a corollary precedes a theorem. So I should rename them. When I told him that it feels strange to me to call them remarks and prove them, he suggested calling them "consequence" ("Folgerung" in German). But this feels somehow arbitrary to me.

I know that many authors have a lot of different naming schemes. 
My question is:
**Is there an author/institution that has a consistant naming scheme and writes why he/she chose this scheme?**

This is what I think is commonly used:

- Propositions are not as important as Theorems
- Corollaries and Lemmata (is the plural correct?) are used to prove theorems
- Theorems are the most important statements

Although Wikipedia has a good list to define and distinguish the terms (see [Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem#Terminology)) all of the cites go to "Wentworth, G.; Smith, D.E. (1913). "Art. 46, 47". Plane Geometry. Ginn & Co." which I can't access.

**Is there a source that explains or defines terms like Theorem, Proposition, Lemma and Corollary?**

(The source does not necessarily need to be an online resource. I can access quite a lot with university: http://www.bibliothek.kit.edu/cms/index.php)

Comment: I think everything you say about common use is correct *except* for corollary. A corollary is a quick result that follows *from* a theorem, often an application. A lemma is a technical result that is useful in proving a theorem.

Comment: Also note that although theorems (and propositions) are supposedly the big results, history has proven people wrong on occation. Zorn's lemma and the regularity lemma are two examples of results that have surpassed their intended use and really become full-fledged theorems in themselves (but kept their names).